# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined" when drawing on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm getting the above error whenever I call my function that should simply draw a circle on a canvas. The error occurs on the line `var ctx = c.getContext("2d");` My document is laid out as such:

The function that should draw the circle is in the head:

```
function circleTrans() {
  var c = $(this).find('canvas')[0];
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

The event that calls the function is also in the head, after the above.:

```
$(".projectContainer").click(function(){
  circleTrans();
});
```

So when clicking on one of the multiple "projectContainer" divs the canvas in that respective div should draw a circle. Here is where the projectContainer is, later in the body:

```
    <div class="projectContainer" name="Film Festival">
        <canvas class="canvases"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Anyone know the cause of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're calling the function, `this` is not the element.

Reference it like this to get the right value of `this`

```
$(".projectContainer").on('click', circleTrans);
```

Comment: This works, thanks :). Out of curiosity, what is "this" referencing when run the way I had?

Comment: It was probably referencing the window or document, you can check that by doing `console.log(this)`

Answer (score 0):

As Adeneo said, `this` is not element, there is another way through which you can pass the element like,

```
$(".projectContainer").click(function(){
  circleTrans(this);
  //pass element-^
});
```

Get `div` element as parameter `cthis`

```
function circleTrans(cthis) {
              //--------^
  var c = $(cthis).find('canvas')[0];
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```